# EditItemTemplate: a conditional binding

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edititemtemplate

According to a specific row value (Type), I must use a TextBox or a DropDownlist inside an EditTemplateField (only ONE of them).
How can I bind conditionally controls inside the EditItemTemplate in order to tell the UpdateMethod which is the control to take into consideration for the field "Value"?

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>'></asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListValue" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Value") %>'>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The GridView's UpdateMethod has "Value" as input parameter and it must be able to decide if taking it from DropDownListValue or TextBoxValue.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODSResults" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetDataByIdDevice" 
    TypeName="DataSetSWCTableAdapters.DispositivoParametro_TableAdapter" 
    UpdateMethod="Save">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="IdDevice" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ProfileParameter Name="Culture" PropertyName="Cultura" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ParameterCode" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="IdDevice" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="IdParameter" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Value" Type="Int64" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I tried to hide/show the controls TextBoxValue and DropDownListValue (using the property "Visible") but it does not work: UI is fine but the UpdateMethod always receives 0 as input value (I guess as result of an empty string casting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use of `RowDatabound Event` of Gridview should solve your problem...refer the code below...

```
 protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         { 
            if( e.Row.RowState==DataControlRowState.Edit)
               {
                  DropDownList drpctrl =(DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[CellIndex].FindControl("DropDownListValue");
                  TextBox  txtCntrl=(TextBox )e.Row.Cells[CellIndex].FindControl("TextBoxValue");
                  if(YuorCondition)
                    {
                        drpctrl.Visible=true/false;
                        txtCntrl.Visible=true/false;

                        ODSResults.UpdateMethod = "Save";
                        ODSResults.InputParameters.Clear(); 
                        ODSResults.InputParameters.Add("IdDevice", "Value1");
                                  ODSResults.InputParameters.Add("IdParameter", "Value2");
                        ODSResults.InputParameters.Add("Value", dropdownValue/Textbox Value);
                    }
               }

         }
     }
```

Comment: See my comment to naveen's answer

Comment: i didn't get your point...which update method are you talking about?

Comment: The GridView's data source has an update method. One of the input parameters of the update method is "Value". I edited my post to explain better this part.

Comment: sorry for late reply,I have edited answer,please check wheather it works for you...

Comment: Your proposal is almost OK for me. I set visibility in the RowCreated event and the DataSource's input parameters definition (for the UpdateMethod) in the RowUpdating event. In this way it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Markup

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxValue" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>'
        Visible='<%# ShouldTextBoxBeVisible(Bind("Type")) %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListValue" runat="server" 
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Value") %>'
        Visible='<%# ShouldDropDownBeVisible(Bind("Type")) %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code-Behind

```
protected bool ShouldTextBoxBeVisible(object objType)
{
    return (objType != null && objType.ToString() == "TextBoxVisibleType");
}
protected bool ShouldDropDownBeVisible(object objType)
{
    return (objType != null && objType.ToString() == "DropDownVisibleType");
}
```

Comment: UI is ok but UpdateMethod still doesn't know which is the proper binding source. In my specific case, the UpdateMethod has an integer paramater and its value is 0 (I guess 0 comes from a casting from an empty string) when the Update is confirmed.